# How to push the text to the right side of a flex <p> element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet below, I have a 2x2 grid made in flex. The problem I have with it is that the text inside the top right and bottom right `<p>` elements are on the left side of the `<p>` and I would prefer if I could push them to the right side. I've tried fiddling with `justify-content: flex-end;` but it doesn't seem to do anything in my case.

```css
.stats-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.stats-container > p {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats-container">
    <p>Likes</p>
    <p>Views</p>
    <p>Comments</p>
    <p>
        <a class='downloadImage' href="">
            <span class='specific-image-text'>Download</span>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align:right` and select the right children with `p:nth-child(even)` :

```css
.stats-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.stats-container > p {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.stats-container > p:nth-child(even){
   text-align:right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="stats-container">
    <p>Likes</p>
    <p>Views</p>
    <p>Comments</p>
    <p>
        <a class='downloadImage' href="">
            <span class='specific-image-text'>Download</span>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```